# TDD for IMDB html scraper

Tags: tdd, imdb

I'm currently developing a TDD idmb html scraper which ill extract certain fields from the imdb webpage. Eg. Title, Synopsis,Cast etc in C++.

I'm just wondering if i have done the TDD right , i have 2 classes the Parser Class & MatchPattern class.

The parser class has like a loadfile function that loads the file into a string and then starts calling the various matchpatttern functions like MatchPattern::extractTitle(string filecontents) and stores them in Parsers' private variables.

the matchpattern is essentially a utility class with static functions. I have no problem testing the matchpattern class. But as for parser class? how should i have designed it for TDD. Am i doing it right or is there something wrong?

Comment: If you don't have IMDB's written consent then yes, something is wrong :)  See http://www.imdb.com/help/show_article?conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't design it *for* TDD, you design it *using* TDD... By writing the test first your design will automatically be testable. Think "How do I want to use this and how can I test it in a simple way". That's where to start.